# Does this happen to a king in S7 as well?

Tags: game-of-thrones

It appears that in every past season of Game of Thrones, exactly once, a king dies:

> 1. Robert Baratheon (S1E7)
>  2. Renly Baratheon (S2E5)
>  3. Robb Stark (S3E9)
>  4. Joffrey Baratheon (S4E2)
>  5. Stannis Baratheon (S5E10)
>  6. Tommen Baratheon (S6E10)

Now that the Season 7 is over, by going over the episodes, I do not remember this happening to a king. Of course the definition of "king" is highly debatable: everyone can claim to be one, but we know that *power resides where men believe it resides.*

So maybe I am simply not looking at things from the right angle. For instance, a possible exception is that in Season 1

> Viserys Targaryen dies (S1E6).

**Has an event of this kind happened in Season 7 as well?**

Bonus question: Was this a coincidence in the past seasons, or are there indications that it was planned along by the writers/author?

Comment: -1.  Sorry - seems a little trvial to me. No - no-one who has used the title King died in S7, yes its a coincidence that there has been at least one such death in each other season.

Comment: This appears to be trivia - I voted to close this question.

Comment: @iandotkelly I agree, if the answer is "duh, no" then it's a boring question. But maybe the answer is "you forgot about X", or "Dickon Tarly was a secret Targaryen".

Comment: Balon Greyjoy, the King of the Iron Islands (and the last king in the War of the 5 kings) also dies in S6E02. So that even more explicitly breaks the pattern of one king season.

Comment: Also King beyond the Wall. And also Rickon Stark, at the time of his death. Since everyone thought Bran and Rickon are dead, lords chose Jon. At the moment of Battle of Bastards, only Jon and Sam know Bran might be still alive, but everyone else thinks he's dead. So after Robb's death, Rickon would be new King in the North.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it like the previous kings, no there was no fallen king this season.

However, it's not a king but royalty dies with the "Queen" of Thorns. Also Viserion (at least in the books) was the first hatched in the fire and one could view that as a king of dragons of sort being first born. But from the logical point of view the only kings left are Euron Grayjoy (King of the Iron Islands), Jon Snow (King in the North), and The Night King. So no, none died.

For your bonus question: this is most likely a coincidence due simply to the volatile world the story takes place in and how easily the writers were willing to kill off characters. I haven't seen any mention by the writers or by George Martin that the trend in the first 6 seasons was planned.